# React app - upload and read JSON file into variable without a server?

Tags: reactjs, express, upload

I'm building a JSON editor in React and right now I'm just fetching a json file from a static folder on the server and sticking it in a variable. I'd like to be able to use a file input and select any json file and read it into the variable.

Is this possible without a server?

That said, I also tried using an Express/Cors server but it's a bit outside my wheelhouse and I'm not sure how to install / run it on the production domain where this editor will live.

Comment: Yes. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader. You can have user select a file and read its content on the browser itself.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have an input of type file and maintain a state and update the state upon `onChange`

[working demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/read-json-file-and-store-in-var-c3s8k?file=/src/Upload.jsx)

**Code snippet**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function Upload({ children }) {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
    fileReader.onload = e => {
      console.log("e.target.result", e.target.result);
      setFiles(e.target.result);
    };
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Upload Json file - Example</h1>

      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      {"uploaded file content -- " + files}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is `req.open("POST", "https://slash-web-null.herokuapp.com/upload");` ? Is this actually loading the json into a stateless variable or storing in some database? Will this break once heroku commits suicide in October? https://www.theregister.com/2022/08/25/heroku_delete_inactive_free_tier/

Comment: May I ask why we need  fileReader.readAsText here? And if we could direcly get the inner content of input tag by e.target.result, and then setFiles, why do we need fileReader here? @openSourcerer

Comment: @AeLeung e.target.result is the value returned by the parameter of filereader.onload callback. He named both parameters the same, thats why it confused you. e.target.result is not the same "e" variable as e.target.files defined in the parent scope.